# Batch easy instance counter

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a quiz for my school, but I need something to simplify the marks counting. Basically what I need it to do is, in 1 line preferably, count how many of the letter 'I' there is in a document and then e.g. if there is 12 I want it to then type into a file, using echo >>, the number of I's there were in that document and then delete the old document, then do that several times over in other documents.

Comment: Do you want to count multiple letter `i` if there are more than one on a line?  Or just how many lines contain the letter `i`?

Answer (score 0):

```
for %%a in (*.txt) do @for /f "delims=" %%b in ('cmd /q /u /c "type "%%a""^|find /c "i"') do @( >>datalist echo %%a %%b & echo del "%%a")
```